# How can I vectorize this loop which uses a pandas dataframe as a lookup table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "data" which has 5 columns, the first is a start time and the second is an end time. I have a second dataframe called "all_times" which is a sorted dataframe of all the start and end times with a concurrent counter calculated by taking the cumulative sum of a value over time. Each start time is +1 to the value, each end time is -1 to the value. I am trying to find the min/max of the concurrent number over the range in each "data" row.

I've come up with a loop shown below which works for my purposes, but is very slow. How can I vectorize this loop?

```
data['min_concurrent'] = 0
data['max_concurrent'] = 0

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    timeranges = all_times[data.iloc[i,0]:data.iloc[i,1]]['cumsum']
    data.iloc[i,5] = timerange['cumsum'].min()
    data.iloc[i,6] = timerange['cumsum'].max()
```

Example of desired output:

```
start                   end                     ... min  max
2017-01-01 00:00:02.187 2017-01-01 00:00:02.437 ...  1    1
2017-01-01 00:00:03.000 2017-01-01 00:00:04.000 ...  1    2
2017-01-01 00:00:03.700 2017-01-01 00:00:05.000 ...  1    2
2017-01-01 00:00:04.100 2017-01-01 00:00:04.200 ...  2    2
2017-01-01 00:00:04.500 2017-01-01 00:00:06.000 ...  1    2
```

Above is also the shape of "data", below is the shape of "all_times":

```
timestamp                value     cumsum
2017-01-01 00:00:02.187  +1          1
2017-01-01 00:00:02.437  -1          0
2017-01-01 00:00:03.000  +1          1
2017-01-01 00:00:03.700  +1          2
2017-01-01 00:00:04.000  -1          1
2017-01-01 00:00:04.100  +1          2
2017-01-01 00:00:04.200  -1          1
2017-01-01 00:00:04.500  +1          2
2017-01-01 00:00:05.000  -1          1
2017-01-01 00:00:06.000  -1          0
```

So, is there a way to make this faster with vector/matrix operations?